# Internet is unbearably & abnormally slow on one PC after recovery using sony recovery partition

Tags: windows-7, networking, laptop, internet-speed

I recently restored a laptop, a custom SONY VPCF1390X, using the built-in recovery partition. Everything went about as well as I expected, but I noticed that download speeds were much lower than what I usually get. I've checked my network speed on the laptop and on other PCs I own and it seems to be the only one affected, what takes less than a minute to download on my desktop takes hours on this laptop, And there were no network problems before I restored it.

My first thought was to download the drivers, which is actually what I was trying to do when I noticed speed discrepancy. So I checked Sony's page and my drivers were up-to-date. I downloaded and installed them anyway, in hopes that it may fix it, but it did nothing.

Since then I've changed ISPs and went from 5mbps (which was closer to 3mbps) to 40-41mbps. But still had the same awful performance, it didn't even scale with the upgrade, stayed basically the same. It does seem to be sporadic, though very frequent, enough that the slow is the norm, with very small bursts of speed every once in a while.

I've even taken the computer to work and used the network there with no effect. My original idea was to restore this computer back to a fresh state so that I could use it in my job, but as a programmer, I often need to download large files and use the internet to research solutions, so I'm stuck with my previous laptop until I can fix this problem.

PS: Problem exists when connected either by cable or wireless.

Here is a post with the laptop's specifications:

http://pastebin.com/7Jb6aYQG

Also an out of ipconfig /all:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Anvil
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.11(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, April 24, 2014 8:47:05 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, April 24, 2014 9:47:05 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 24.55.102.2
                                       24.138.234.252
                                       24.55.102.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8057 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:1027:c53:3f57:fff4(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1027:c53:3f57:fff4%15(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{7E677023-7BBD-4AAD-A03D-2FF40B611264}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Reusable ISATAP Interface {96471925-34B8-4D64-9681-FEE3AEC99F49}:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

EDIT:

Router model is a Cisco DPC3925. But I had a different router (and ISP) when this all started, and I also have the problem while using other connections. The adapter I usually use is the "Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter" since I mostly connect through wi-fi. I have tried the Marvell Yukon LAN port, but it was no different than wireless, so I'm pretty sure it's not a hardware issue.

Could anyone recommend a good Linux build that I may test a theory? Maybe something went wrong in the installation, and Windows is the problem. I'm thinking I can boot into Linux on a Stick and do a speedtest from it maybe it will prove me right or at least point back at the hardware issue...

Comment: After you do this recovery, did you wonder when this recovery partiton was made, and how many updates came after it? The title uses the words "system restore" which on windows systems is to retract small changes and could cause an issue or change things without changing others (mixed up) , if it is only a "Recovery" that is different.  Because there are all kinds of servers out there with varying speed at times, did you do a "speed Test" which varies too but is one test.  Then something to use to check your "tcp" parameters is one thing?

Comment: It's the recovery partition that the laptop comes with from Sony, not a System restore created by me. It restored the PC to how it came when I bought it.

Comment: I tested the speed using speedtest.net, and I get around half my bandwidth (15-20 mbps out of 40 mbps). However I also tested by downloading a 200mb file, and Firefox reports it as downloading at 2 mb/s and it continues to drop in speed the longer the download takes. Simple web browsing is bearable, but not fast by any means, and it often gets stuck loading a page, so I have to refresh. Ping seems to be similar to other PCs in the network.

Comment: FYI: 2MB/s **is** 16mpbs

Comment: Do you get the same issues when booting any Linux live distribution?

Comment: They were much worse in Linux Mint... I wanted to try and find drivers for the network controller, but I couldn't find an option for it.

Comment: You should mask MAC addresses in future. I am doing that for you right now.

Comment: Is it slow too when you take that laptop to work and try there? On wlan and on lan?

Comment: Yes on both counts. I tried at work, at home and with a previous ISP. Also Wired and Wireless.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a software problem, here are some suggestions.

It's possible that refreshing has returned some security software that was previously disabled or has reset some other parameters in Windows. Try to :

1. Disable all antivirus and firewall.
2. Try to boot in Safe Mode. If the slowdown doesn't happen in this mode, then some installed product is responsible for it. [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) is a handy tool for disabling startup
   programs that you suspect of being the cause.
3. Fully patch Windows including optional updates (device drivers are always optional).
4. Disable all network adapters except the one that provides Internet.
   Preferably use the wired adapter to reduce the number of factors.
5. Use [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) to scan the integrity of Windows (most probably it won't
   find anything, but just in case).

Remark: The laptop's specifications link that you posted is no longer valid.

Comment: Ok, I disabled antivirus (Microsoft Security Essentials) and the Firewall. I also disabled any network adapters that weren't necessary and used sfc /scannow (returned no errors). I saw no improvement. I also tried Safe Mode, and a Clean Boot with no effect. My Windows is fully patched except for the Bing bar and desktop. I'll try to post a link shortly.

Comment: In view of the fact that it still happens in Safe mode, I fear that something is wrong with the refreshed version of Windows. It would be a very lucky guess indeed to find out where it went wrong (as it's their version of Windows that's bad). You should try first to contact Sony Support, as they might know where the problem is. Otherwise, the easiest solution would probably be to reinstall Windows from an installation media (after saving all the current drivers, serial numbers, and even a disk image if possible - I can supply more info on that).

Answer (score 1):

first you should download Ubuntu Linux desktop CD and start from the CD (or USB with Unetbootin) with out installing it.

if it is slow there too, it seems like your hardware is kind of broken.

if it is fast there it has to be a software problem.

Another blind guess is that you could have another device in your network that gets the same IP or with the same hostname?

Comment: I tried running Mint Live from an USB stick. It went much slower, and barely loaded one page. After loading one page it would sort of hang on every request I tried... I figured that such a bad performance could be due to bad drivers, but I couldn't figure out how to download a different one.

Comment: you should ask at http://askubuntu.com for how to get a new driver for your card and then try again. Or try another USB WiFi stick

Answer (score 0):

Delete your current driver and re-install it. I guess your driver is this one? [WiFi Driver](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCF1390X&upd_id=6043&os_group_id=6)

Use compmgmt.msc to reinstall

Answer (score -1):

I recently did system restore for my Acer laptop Aspire 4743G but the internet connection was very slow. I uninstalled the McAfee Internet Security which was pre-installed. Now, the internet connection has been restored.